# How to fix label in a text field?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitextfield

I'm new on iOS, i'm working on an application which has some text fields. I want that when user click on text field for enter text the label(place holder) should not be removed.[i would like my text fields as displayed in this image](http://www.carettasoftware.com/gallery/images/IPC_ContactInfo_Stage2.png)

Any suggestion or sample code will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel and UITextField are two different classes. You need to build view with static UILabel (User Interaction: NO) and UITextField for entering user provided content. It's easy job with Interface Builder.

Comment: I need a label inside the text field, and it shouldn't be removed when user enter some text in text field.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eponfaaz2hqp3v/ib.png - not much work in IB. Just place UILabel above UITextField.

Comment: Or, within the storyboard, use the 'Text' property of the UITextfield to set some standard text. Be sure to deselect 'Clear when editing begins' to prevent the text from being removed when editing.

Comment: One more help please, when i enter text it overlap the label(when size of text entered goes bigger), How can i fix it?